# Getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS When Using FLAnimatedImage

Tags: ios, xcode, gif, animated-gif

I've following method to perform animated image view:

```
-(void) setTheGifHeigt:(int)screenHeight andWidth:(int)screenWidth andSize:(int)size{
image = [[FLAnimatedImage alloc] initWithAnimatedGIFData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"mygif" ofType:@"gif"]]];
imageView = [[FLAnimatedImageView alloc] init];
imageView.loopCompletionBlock(0);
imageView.animatedImage = image;

imageView.frame = CGRectMake((screenWidth / 2) - (size / 2), (screenHeight / 2) - (size / 2), size, size);
[self.view addSubview:imageView];

}
```

My aim is simple, I want my gif play once. But when i add "looopCompletionBlock" method I get following error:

Thread1:EXC_BAD_ACCESS(Code=1, address=0x10)

Waiting for your helps, thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

You should try providing an actual block instead of zero, as stated in the header file:

`@property (nonatomic, copy) void ( ^ ) ( NSUInteger loopCountRemaining ) loopCompletionBlock`

However, looking at FLAnimatedImage source the only `loopCountRemaining` usage found is in https://github.com/Flipboard/FLAnimatedImage/blob/06d071f674682e90409c648aab60dd50be68bc0f/FLAnimatedImage/FLAnimatedImageView.m#L394, so issue probably does not lay here.

Comment: What do you mean with actual block, can you give an example

Comment: This is a block: ^void(NSUInteger i){  NSLog(@"test");  };